# How can I loop through multiple instances of a JS component

Tags: javascript

I have written some JS for a custom carousel and would like to be able to use unlimited multiple instances of this on the same page

I am aware of the concept of looping through instances, and a few different ways to do this, but am having some trouble with getting this working as a JS beginner

Example: https://codepen.io/kempster/pen/rNOwMaB

JS:

```
  var prev  = document.querySelector('.prev');
  var next  = document.querySelector('.next');
  var counter = document.querySelector('.counter');
  var slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  var currentSlide = 0;

  function prevSlide(){
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';

    if (currentSlide === 0 ) {
      currentSlide = slides.length - 1;
    } else {
      window.currentSlide--;
    }   
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide active';
    updateCounter();
    sliderWrapper.style.width = slides[currentSlide].clientWidth + 'px';
    sliderWrapper.style.height = slides[currentSlide].clientHeight + 'px';
  } 

  function nextSlide(){
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    window.currentSlide++;
    window.currentSlide %= window.slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide active';
    updateCounter();
    sliderWrapper.style.width = slides[currentSlide].clientWidth + 'px';
    sliderWrapper.style.height = slides[currentSlide].clientHeight + 'px';
  } 

  window.onload = function load() {
    sliderWrapper.style.width = slides[currentSlide].clientWidth + 'px';
    sliderWrapper.style.height = slides[currentSlide].clientHeight + 'px';
    counter.innerHTML = (currentSlide + 1) + ' / ' + slides.length;
  }

  function updateCounter() {
    counter.innerHTML = (currentSlide + 1) + ' / ' + slides.length;
  }

  prev.addEventListener('click', () => prevSlide());
  next.addEventListener('click', () => nextSlide());
```

Comment: Why not write a web component?

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is only for very specific questions. You may have more luck on code review. If I were to offer some very quick advice, look into JavaScript prototypes. That's a good cross-browser place to start.

Comment: Create a class/object which holds all the functionality you've written. When it gets instantiated, it should accept parameters such as the DOM element to bind to. Your event listeners and selectors should look within the bound DOM element, not all-encompassing selectors like `.slide` which select *all* `.slide` elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you identify the different carousels on your HTML with some class or ID.
I'd suggest to store somewhere (localStorage, window, whatever fits your needs) an object somewhat like this:

```
const carousels = [
  {
    id: id
    prev: document.querySelector('.prev');
    next: document.querySelector('.next');
    counter: document.querySelector('.counter');
    slides: document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    currentSlide: 0;
  },
  {
    // Etc...
  }
];
```

Or this:

```
const carousels = {
  1: {
    prev: document.querySelector('.prev');
    next: document.querySelector('.next');
    counter: document.querySelector('.counter');
    slides: document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    currentSlide: 0;
  },
  2: {
    // Etc...
  }
};
```

That way you can keep the reference to all the relevant info of all the carousels on a page and inside the events you can check for the ID/class of the carousel triggering the event and use your methods on the correct carousel elements.

**You should also make sure to select in each case the relevant slides and buttons and not all of them as you are doing now.**

It's a quick solution but I hope it helps.